# Contact DISPLAY_NAME Android

Tags: android, android-contacts

I want to insert a new contact with a GIVEN_NAME, FAMILY_NAME and set a display name that will be the one displayed in the contact list, but won't be synchronized with the google account. I tried this:

```
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI) 
        .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex) 
        .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
        .withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, "Name in list")
        .withValue(StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, "RealN")
        .withValue(StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, "RealFN")
        .build()); //FIXME: REMOVE WHEN UPDATING CONTACTS
```

But in the contact list I see: RealN RealFN, when I want to see Name in list.

Comment: See your phone settings for contacts. There is a setting option that tell which part of contact you want to show into list

Comment: Thank you, but I want to do it programmatically...

Comment: The text which you insert into display name, split those and insert into first name, last name and family name.. and don't insert any thing into display name

Comment: My problem is that I want to display a name in the contact list that is completely different from the given and family name. For example: David Hans is the real name but in the contact list I want to see My Love

Comment: Read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Nickname.html which can help